# Generics not performing Type Erasure

Tags: java, generics

Following code is throwing  `java.lang.ArrayStoreException` exception. To my understanding compiler should generate error or warning as I am using `generics`.

Please check the code below and find the commented line.

```
   public class Test1 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Collection<Number> nums = new ArrayList<Number>();
            nums.add(new Integer(1));
            nums.add(new Long(-1));
            //every thing is fine here
            Number[] aa = nums.toArray(new Number[0]);
            for (Number num : aa) {
                System.out.println(num);
            }
            // Even if generics are there,no warning or error is reported by complier
            Integer[] bb= nums.toArray(new Integer[nums.size()]);
            for (Integer integer : bb) {
                System.out.println(integer);
            }

        }

    }
```

Kindly help me understand this behavior. Can you please help me understand how to fix this as well?

Comment: no way for the compiler to know that `nums` cannot be converted to an `Integer` array.

Comment: Warnings are generated for unsafe code, that is, code that can cause heap pollution. Your code is safe because it throws an exception immediately. See also the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray-T:A-).

Comment: So it gets converted to an integer array, but then errors out when you actually try storing `Number` in it.

Comment: Can you tell me how to fix this ???

Comment: What kind of fix you imagine? The static type check is not present in that method, so you'll need to make sure the types are compatible yourself, or face a runtime exception. For most cases, declaring the array the same type as the (static) type of the original list is the way to go.

Comment: There's no "fix" that will allow you to put a `Long` into an `Integer` array.

Comment: Also note that no errors are reported for `String[] bb = nums.toArray(...)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Collection.toArray()` method is defined as:

```
<T> T[] toArray(T[] a);
```

meaning that the type parameter `T` only binds the parameter type to the return value's type. It s independent of any type parameters of the enclosing class (`E` for element type in the case of `Collection`).

Comment: Can you please let me know how can i fix the same in my code

Comment: @Animal use a Number array instead of an Integer array

Comment: Note that even if it weren't defined with a free type variable (or indeed you were to provide a type constraint `<Number>` to the `toArray` method http://ideone.com/NTzzoS), you would still be able to pass an `Integer[]` to the method requiring a `Number[]`, because Java arrays are covariant. Just another example of where arrays and generics don't play nicely together.